# VSCode Remote-SSH breaks when the DefaultShell parameter in Open SSH is not Windows Command Line

Tags: git-bash, openssh, vscode-remote

When the DefaulShell is set to e.g. git bash in OpenSSH on my remote machine, VSCode Remote-SSH fails to connect. This is fixed when I change it to cmd. Is there a way to fix this as I would prefer OpenSSH to use git bash.

My client is a Windows 10 machine and my remote machine is Windows Server 2012 R2.